# Display median / mean

Tags: grouping, stata, median

I'm new to Stata and have been through the help files and did some searches but I can't find what I'm looking for. I want to see the median of a variable I created by each group without having to list the detail.

I have a binary variable with values 1 or 0 called `groupbyvar` and the variable I want the median for `var1`

my code:

```
bysort groupbyvar: egen median_var1 = median(var1)
```

This works but now I want to see two values one for `groupbyvar = 0` and one for `groupbyvar = 1` respectively. How do I achieve this?

If I use `list groupbyvar median_var1` I get what I want but I have to go through all the data and if I use `display median_var1` I only see the value for one of the groupbyvar's values

Comment: Why not just cross-tabulate the two with tab groupbyvar median_var1

Comment: Spelling is "Stata" and has been so for >30 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you have done, this would give a minimal display

```
tabdisp bygroupvar, c(median_var1)
```

and indeed if all you want is a display, there is no need to create a variable first.

Here is a reproducible example

```
. sysuse auto, clear

. tabstat mpg, s(median) by(foreign)

Summary for variables: mpg
     by categories of: foreign (Car type)

 foreign |       p50
---------+----------
Domestic |        19
 Foreign |      24.5
---------+----------
   Total |        20
--------------------
```

and study of the help for `tabstat` would show the scope for looking at single summary statistics, as you request, and at several.

Comment: Perfect thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers